How to draw attention after the end of a bounty?
The bounty as ended on one of my question and it is still unanswered (one response but not accurate, downvoted to -1). How to draw more attention to this question ? 
Is there a feature to draw more attention ? or good/bad practice ?

The feature to draw more attention is the bounty. So you could give a new one but I imagine you're reluctant to do that.
The long term solution is to have more quality users on this site. In the short term, you could politely reach out to someone in the know and ask him or her to answer it.
